# Perform segues when I want

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Evening, I have 2 show segues in my VC. But I want to fires these segues only when my pickerView has a `row.count > 0`.

This is what I have:

```
Override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "searchImages" {

    if pickerView.numberOfRows(inComponent: 0) > 0  {

        let controller = (segue.destination) as! WebViewController
        //replacing " " with "+" for google search queries
        let type: WebViewController.SearchType = .image
        let queryString = String(nameLabel.text!.characters.map {
                    $0 == " " ? "+" : $0
        })
        controller.searchType = type
        controller.queryString = queryString
        print("2")
        }

        }
        if segue.identifier == "searchWiki" {

        if pickerView.numberOfRows(inComponent: 0) > 0  {
            let controller = (segue.destination) as! WebViewController
            //replacing " " with "+" for google search queries
            let type: WebViewController.SearchType = .wiki
            let queryString = String(nameLabel.text!.characters.map {
                    $0 == " " ? "+" : $0
            })
            controller.searchType = type
            controller.queryString = queryString
        }
    }
}
```

I know I should use: `ShouldperformSomething`. But I don't know hot use it.
Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement [shouldPerformSegue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformseguewithidentifier) instead of checking `pickerView.numberOfRows(inComponent: 0) > 0` in your `prepareForSegue` method.

*P.S: Swift 3 Code (I assume that this is what you want).*

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return pickerView.numberOfRows(inComponent: 0) > 0
}
```

Now, `prepareForSegue` method should be similar to:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "searchImages" {
            let controller = (segue.destination) as! WebViewController
            //replacing " " with "+" for google search queries
            let type: WebViewController.SearchType = .image
            let queryString = String(nameLabel.text!.characters.map {
                $0 == " " ? "+" : $0
            })
            controller.searchType = type
            controller.queryString = queryString
            print("2")

        }

        if segue.identifier == "searchWiki" {
            let controller = (segue.destination) as! WebViewController
            //replacing " " with "+" for google search queries
            let type: WebViewController.SearchType = .wiki
            let queryString = String(nameLabel.text!.characters.map {
                $0 == " " ? "+" : $0
            })
            controller.searchType = type
        }
    }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: thank you! so the shouldPerformSegue is automatically called before performing the segue?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be doing the check on the prepare delegate of the UIStoryboardSegue, but on the shouldPerform:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    return pickerView.numberOfRows(inComponent: 0) > 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you be more specified on how can I implement it in my code?

Comment: Just add it to your ViewController. Whenever a segue is to be performed, this delegate method will be called and it's up to you and your logic to return YES or NO to allow the segue to be performed or not